# Possibility to use multiple Cache directory with OkHttp

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I'm wondering if okHttp offer the ability to manage multiple cache directories in parallel and how to implement it...
Use case I want to implement is :

- user browse random URL that are cached in cacheDir1 with evictionPolicy1
- user is able to save URL contents in cacheDir2 with a dedicated evictionPolicy2 != evictionPolicy1

When loading an URL, okHttp will look at cache2 first, then cache1, saving URL content in cache 1 if not already present in cache1 or cache2

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in OkHttp. I recommend doing this at another layer; perhaps an application interceptor.